# Jenkins: run batch locally on slave

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, auto-build

I need Jenkins to be able to run batch file on slave locally with parameters. I've tried to use PSExec tool, but it does not run when Jenkins tries to do it (slave: windows 7 x86 OS). xCmd cannot be run locally. Can anybody suggest some tools or some way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSExec works for me on Windows 7 x64. Solved.